# Ordered cross ratios for the uniform matroid

Tags: co.combinatorics

At the moment I am studying a proof by Gel'fand, Rybnikov and Stone (Theorem 4 in the paper "[Projective Orientations of Matroids](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870885710365/1-s2.0-S0001870885710365-main.pdf?_tid=f96a02ac-0c5d-11e6-bcbd-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1461751023_c257066ea94fdec2da4528116286f6b5)"). To be more precise, I am try ing to describe a new presentation by generators and relations for the inner Tutte groups of a matroid.

I find a result. However, it would be nice to compute some examples in the uniform case. Here is my problem.

Let $U_{d}(m)$ be the uniform matroid of rank $d$ with ground set $E$ of $m$ elements and let us write $\mathfrak{C}$  for its set of circuits. Let us fix an arbitrary enumeration $\{C_{d}\}_{d\in D}$ for $\mathfrak{C}$ and a total order $<$ on $D$.

Let us consider the set $\mathbb{W}$ of symbols 
$[C_{i_{1}}C_{i_{2}}|C_{i_{3}}C_{i_{4}}]$ where $C_{i_{h}}\in\mathfrak{C}$ 
for $1\leq h \leq 4$ with the extra conditions:

1) $|C_{i_{1}}\cup C_{i_{2}}\cup C_{i_{3}}\cup C_{i_{4}}|=d+2$

2) $i_{1}\neq i_{3}$ and $i_{1}\neq i_{4}$ and 
   $i_{2}\neq i_{3}$ and $i_{2}\neq i_{4}$

In a similar way, let us write $\mathcal{W}$ for the set of symbols 
$(C_{j_{1}}C_{j_{2}}|C_{j_{3}}C_{j_{4}})$ where $C_{j_{k}}\in\mathfrak{C}$ 
for $1\leq k \leq 4$ with the extra conditions:

1) $|C_{j_{1}}\cup C_{j_{2}}\cup C_{j_{3}}\cup C_{j_{4}}|=d+2$

2) $j_{1}<j_{2}$ and $j_{3}<j_{4}$ and $j_{1}<j_{3}$

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Compute the cardinality of $\mathbb{W}$ and $\mathcal{W}$.